# Can't talk to dev Google Cloud module

Tags: android-studio

I have an Android Studio project that contains the android app and a backend Google Cloud Module. I am having problems with the IP address of the development backend. In the examples in the Android docs it says to use `10.0.2.2`, which I have tried and I always get a 20sec timeout. I have also tried to use my development machine's ip, which also results in a reported 20sec timeout, even though it fails immediately. In both of the previous cases the server is verified to be running by manually loading `localhost:8080` in the browser.

```
// Async task snippet
protected Joke doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    if(mApiService == null) {  // Only do this once
        MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                // options for running against local devappserver
                // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                .setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                    @Override
                    public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                        abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                    }
                });
        mApiService = builder.build();
    }

    try {
        String text = mApiService.sayHi("Chris").execute().getData();
        return new Joke(text);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "fetch: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I missed the text snippet in regards to the ip address being for running within an emulator, where as I was testing it on a usb connected device.  Running it via the emulator worked just fine :)